# Remove rows from table based on column value using self join

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a requirement where my data looks like below. I have to find the ids from the table where the last pid status is not "removed".

Note:-
1. To get the last pid status use the "date" and "hour" columns.
2. If for an "id", a pid's last "status" value is removed then  don't include that row in the result.

```
id  |   key    |    date     |  hour    | pid  | status
--------------------------------------------------------
id1 |   one    |    20180618 |  2       |  p1  | added
id1 |   one    |    20180618 |  3       |  p1  | removed
id1 |   one    |    20180618 |  4       |  p1  | added
id1 |   one    |    20180618 |  4       |  p2  | added

id1 |   one    |    20180619 |  2       |  p1  | removed
id1 |   one    |    20180619 |  4       |  p1  | added
id1 |   one    |    20180619 |  4       |  p2  | removed
id1 |   one    |    20180619 |  5       |  p3  | added

id2 |   one    |    20180619 |  5       |  p1  | added
id2 |   one    |    20180619 |  5       |  p2  | added
id2 |   one    |    20180619 |  6       |  p1  | removed
```

Expected output:-

```
id  |   key    |    date     |  hour    | pid  | status
--------------------------------------------------------
id1 |   one    |    20180619 |  4       |  p1  | added
id1 |   one    |    20180619 |  5       |  p3  | added
id2 |   one    |    20180619 |  5       |  p2  | added
```

I don't want to delete the data from the source table.
I want to query the source table to produce the above result  using self join.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `row_number()` function to identify the latest record for each combination of `id` and `pid` and then it's easy to select only those with the status you want, like so:

```
declare @SampleData table (id varchar(32), [key] varchar(32), [date] date, [hour] int, pid varchar(32), [status] varchar(32));
insert @SampleData values
    ('id1', 'one', '20180618', 2, 'p1', 'added'),
    ('id1', 'one', '20180618', 3, 'p1', 'removed'),
    ('id1', 'one', '20180618', 4, 'p1', 'added'),
    ('id1', 'one', '20180618', 4, 'p2', 'added'),
    ('id1', 'one', '20180619', 2, 'p1', 'removed'),
    ('id1', 'one', '20180619', 4, 'p1', 'added'),
    ('id1', 'one', '20180619', 4, 'p2', 'removed'),
    ('id1', 'one', '20180619', 5, 'p3', 'added'),
    ('id2', 'one', '20180619', 5, 'p1', 'added'),
    ('id2', 'one', '20180619', 5, 'p2', 'added'),
    ('id2', 'one', '20180619', 6, 'p1', 'removed');

with OrderedDataCTE as
(
    select
        S.id, S.[key], S.[date], S.[hour], S.pid, S.[status],
        [sequence] = row_number() over (partition by S.id, S.pid order by S.[date] desc, S.[hour] desc)
    from
        @SampleData S
)
select
    O.id, O.[key], O.[date], O.[hour], O.pid, O.[status]
from
    OrderedDataCTE O
where
    O.[sequence] = 1 and
    O.[status] != 'removed';
```

Answer (score 1):

The [`last_value`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/last-value-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) window function could allow you to do this without a join:

```
SELECT id, key, date, hour, pid, status
FROM   (SELECT id, key, date, hour, pid, status,
               LAST_VALUE(status) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY data ASC, hour ASC) AS lv
        FROM   mytable) t
WHERE   lv <> 'removed'
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're asking for a solution with a self-join.

Here's a solution using a self-join:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM YourTable t
LEFT JOIN YourTable r
ON ( r.id = t.id AND r.pid = t.pid AND r.[status] = 'removed'
     AND dateadd(hour,r.hour,cast(r.date AS datetime)) >= dateadd(hour,t.hour,cast(t.date as datetime))
)
WHERE r.[status] IS NULL
ORDER BY t.id, t.pid, t.date, t.hour;
```

But I would prefere the NOT EXISTS version

```
SELECT *
FROM YourTable t
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1 
    FROM YourTable r
    WHERE r.id = t.id AND r.pid = t.pid AND r.[status] = 'removed'
     AND dateadd(hour,r.hour,cast(r.date AS datetime)) >= dateadd(hour,t.hour,cast(t.date as datetime))
)
ORDER BY t.id, t.pid, t.date, t.hour;
```

**Both return:**

```
id  key date       hour pid status
--- --- ---------- ---- --- ------
id1 one 2018-06-19    4 p1  added
id1 one 2018-06-19    5 p3  added
id2 one 2018-06-19    5 p2  added
```

Comment: @LukeStorms What if I want to count the no of times in the above question the product is added for the user for which last status is not removed. Can I do this in a single query ?

Comment: Maybe via a window function? F.e.: `select t.*, count(*) over (partition by t.id, t.pid) as total_same_pid ...` .

Comment: @dks551 Or if you want a reverse row_number based on the pid? f.e. `row_number(*) over (partition by t.id, t.pid order by dateadd(hour,t.hour,cast(t.date as datetime)) desc) as rn`

Comment: because the above query returns me the last row with status not equals to removed, so if I include this "select t.*, count(*) over (partition by t.id, t.pid) as total_same_pid" then the count is always 1. What I want is basically get me the total count per day of this pid for the id for which the last status is removed.
eg:-
id1  one   2018-06-18  p1  total-count(2)
id1  one   2018-06-19  p1  total-count(1)
So, can we do this in a single query ?

Comment: What does the reverse row_number give you?